# Where can I find prices for alcohol?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pricing, pathfinder-society

I want my PFS character to spend some gold on drinking and tempt others to do it.

However, the [rules that I have found](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-creations/drinking-rules/) lack actual price listing of different alcohol beverages.

**Where can I find those prices?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're listed in the [Goods and Services](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/hunting-camping-survival-gear/#table-food-drink) item list. There's a bunch of alcoholic beverages there, ranging from common ales and meads to absinthe, whiskey and wine. Most of them are sourced from the core rules or the *Ultimate Equipment* supplement.

Comment: Damn, those Wasp Mead prices.